# What is the minimal order of a “sigmoid-like” entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

The following question is motivated by [Is there a complex analytic function that acts like sigmoid on the reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390467/is-there-a-complex-analytic-function-that-acts-like-sigmoid-on-the-reals):

> What is the minimal order of an entire function $f$ which is real-valued, increasing, and bounded on the real axis?

In the above-referenced Q&A an additional condition is imposed on the second derivative, which I have omitted here for simplicity.

The [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type) of an entire function $f$ is defined as
$$
\rho(f) = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log \log M(r, f)}{\log r}
$$
where $ M(r, f) = \max \{ |f(z)| : |z| = r \}$ is the maximum of $|f|$ on the circle with radius $r$.

The order of an entire function is equal to the order of its derivative (see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4318902/42969)), therefore an equivalent question is

> What is the minimal order of an entire function $h$ which is real-valued, positive, and integrable on the real axis?

The answer must be a value between $1$ and $2$:

- The function $h(z) = \exp(-z^2)$ satisfies these conditions and has order $2$, so that is an upper bound for the minimal order. The corresponding function $f(z) = \int_0^z f(t) \, dt$ is – apart from a constant factor – the [Gauss error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).
- On the other hand, the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle_for_a_sector_in_the_complex_plane) shows that $\rho(f) \ge 1$ for any entire function which is bounded on the real axis.

Some thoughts:

- The easiest way to construct admissible function $h$ of finite order would be to set $h(z) = \exp(p(z))$ with a polynomial $p$ with real coefficients. But in order to make $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x) \, dx$ finite, the degree of $p$ must be at least $2$, so that does not lead to a better upper bound.
- $f(z) = \sin(z)$ has order one, is real-valued and bounded on the real axis, but is not increasing on the real axis. The question is whether the monotony condition enforces a larger order or not.

Any examples or results which improve the lower or upper bound are welcome.

Comment: $\int_0^z \frac{\sin^2(s)}{s^2}ds$ has order $1$

Comment: @reuns: Indeed, that is (unless I am mistaken, and apart from a constant factor) what you get when you choose $h(t) = t$ and $a=1$ in Conrad's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is $1$ as follows; first it is enough to find $g$ (entire non zero, order $1$) nonnegative and integrable on the real line, so $M=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx < \infty, g(x)\ge 0, x \in \mathbb R$ as then $f(z)=\int_{[0,z]}g(t)dt$ works, since for $x<y, f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^yg(t)dt$ and $g(t)>0$ except possible at countably many discrete zeroes so in particular on some small interval in $(x,y)$ while clearly $-M < f(x) <M$, $f$ is entire and of order $1$ by general theory

But now pick any nonzero $h \in L^2(-a,a)$ with some $a>0$ and by [Paley Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) (very easy part - converse is the difficult part) $G(z)=\int_{-a}^ah(t)e^{izt}dt$ is an entire (nonzero) exponential function (order $1$ functions are also called exponential for obvious reasons) of type $a$ which is square integrable on any horizontal line, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|G(x+iy)|^2dx < \infty$ for any fixed $y \in \mathbb R$.

If we take $h$ odd, then $G$ is conjugate invariant since $$G(x) =\int_{-a}^ah(t)(\cos xt+i\sin xt)=\int_{-a}^ah(t)\cos xtdt, x \in \mathbb R$$

Then if we take $g(z)=G(z)\overline {G(\bar z)}$ (or $g(z)=G^2(z)$ if $G$ is conjugate invariant), one clearly has $g$ entire non zero, $g(x) \ge 0$ for real $x$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|G(x)|^2dx< \infty$, while $g$ is of order $1$ and type $2a$ by general theory

(note that if one wants, one can obtain a strictly positive $g$ by an elaboration of the above, picking a $y$ where $G$ has no zeroes on the horizontal line $x+iy$ and defining $G_1(z)=G(z+iy)$ and using the square integrability of $G$ on the horizontal line passing through $iy$) etc)

Edit later; choose $a=1, h(t)=t/|t|$ the signum of $t \ne 0$ so $G(z)=2\int_0^1\cos ztdt=\frac{2}{z}\sin z$ so $g(z)=4\frac{\sin^2(z)}{z^2}$ is the example of @reuns in the comment above

Comment: Very nice! One could perhaps add a concrete example (see @reuns comment at the question).

Comment: added that in text, no problem - note that you need $h$ the signum functions here (for $h=t$ one gets a slightly more complicated function)